# learning php unset ()

Tags: php

3 and learning from a book (php a begginers guide, vikram vaswani)
and am following his guides and have entered his code

```
$whoami="sarah";
echo gettype ($whoami);

$whoami=99.8;
echo gettype ($whoami);

unset ($whoami);
echo gettype ($whoami);
```

the error i am getting is this

```
Undefined variable: whoami in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\etc..
```

I was hoping someone could explain why?
also, off topic but if anyone knows if this book is anygood or not for a complete begginer could they recommend a better one as i have had quite a few errors when entering code ?

thankyou

Comment: This is what is meant to happen – you unset it, then tried to get the type, which is an error.

Comment: unset ($whoami);
undefines the variable $whami. SO again calling
echo gettype ($whoami);
results in that error

Comment: Everything is fine! You just learned how it looks like when a variable was unset. :-) Keep going... :-)

Comment: lol i just spent the last two hours trying to fix it, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you use **unset()** to destroy a variable.

But there are a few subtleties:

> **unset()** destroys the specified variables.
>
> The behavior of **unset()** inside of a function can vary depending on
>   what type of variable you are attempting to destroy.
>
> If a globalized variable is *unset()* inside of a function, only the
>   local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment
>   will retain the same value as before *unset()* was called.

*Source: the [unset() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)*.

Answer (score 2):

Good day friend, unset in php is to destroy anything in your case you put inside a variable unset and delo why the error happened because he destroyed the variable and when you try to use the code below her she was no more.